# Go gin binding with interface

Tags: go, go-gin

Full code here
https://go.dev/play/p/5_U8onnbn_1

I send a request `http://localhost:8080/api/ping?query=qwe` but query is nil

How to bind a struct implemented interface?

Is it possible? If yes, how?

```golang
type Service interface {
    Execute() (output any, err error)
}

type Example struct {
    Query string `json:"query" form:"query"`
}

// implement Service...

func Wrap(req Service) func(c *gin.Context) {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        err := c.ShouldBindWith(&req, binding.Query)
        if err != nil {
            return
        }
        fmt.Println(req) // Here I got this: { <nil> }
    }
}

func main() {
    r := gin.Default()
    r.GET("/ping", Wrap(Example{}))
    r.Run()
}
```

Comment: Hi there! To help us better understand your issue, could you please provide a minimal reproducible example (MRE) that demonstrates the problem? This should include the code necessary to reproduce the issue, as well as any relevant data or input files. Providing an MRE will make it easier for us to diagnose and solve the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I upload MRE.

Comment: Don't edit your question to include the answer. If you find your own answer, hit the answer button and provide an answer below.

Comment: Your 'full' example is short enough to include in the question itself, without linking to an external site. You should just include it in the question.

I also agree with Jonathan - please move your answer to an actual answer, and not just as text in the question. It makes the question and answer easier to read for anyone needing this information in the future!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to do basic reading, going through examples that will help

1. [struct implement interface](https://go.dev/tour/methods/10)
2. gin-gonic sample example to understand how you can implement gin servers [gin-gonic-examples](https://github.com/gin-gonic/examples)

**Below is basic example based on yours**

```
type Server struct{}

func (s *Server) Wrap() func(c *gin.Context) {
  return func(c *gin.Context) {
    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, "pong")
  }
}

func main() {
 r := gin.Default()
 group := r.Group("")
 server := &Server{}
 group.GET("/ping", server.Wrap())
 r.Run(":8080")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer provided by OP with an edit to the question, moved here.

---

I found the problem... it's already pointer. so just pass param into ShouldBindWith

```golang
err := c.ShouldBindWith(req, binding.Query)
```